# Disimporting a package in python

Tags: python, keras, package, progress-bar, tqdm

I'm working with tensorflow.keras and tqdm packages at the same time. But they have some conflict. I have updated both but the problem has not been solved. The problem is that when I import tqdm, the progress bar of Keras does not work properly. So, I want to dis-import(!) tqdm when I'm done with that.

Is there any solution?

---

**Update:**

[a simple code with this issue](http://s8.picofile.com/file/8340155718/31.PNG)

```
#importing packages and data

import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm as q
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)=tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# a simple use of tqdm, a package for showing progressbar

for i in q(range(1000)):
    pass

# making a simple model for neural network using keras

model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))
model.compile('adam','sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train,validation_split=0.1)
```

Comment: Instead of trying to remove imported packages you can import packages under an alias, like `from a import b as c` to avoid conflicts. Bear in mind that you need to reference it as `c` from now on, like `c.sort(x)`

Comment: @Johan I tried that, It doesn't work...

Comment: Can you provide your code in your question? Because it sounds like something that should/could be solved without removing imported packages (I don't even know if it's possible). Alternatively you can import packages locally in functions.

Comment: @Johan Thanks for your time... I 've added. How can I import locally?

Comment: I have literally no idea what I'm looking at. Can you please add the code as code/text in your question and not as an image? Also point out exactly what is causing your error. Bear in mind that I don't know anything about your code, keras or tqdm, but I have proficient knowledge in python and how to avoid packages conflicts.

Comment: @Johan, Done. I sent as pic to see the error. Keras itself has a built-in progress-bar to show the progress of the NN. But when I import tqdm to show the progress of something else, it make keras progress bar to crash.